# Trouble with custom seekBar android

Tags: android, seekbar

i have a trouble with custom seekBar .I used http://android-holo-colors.com/ to give images of seekBar .The problem is a vague beginning of seekBar .  How can i solve this problem?!
ScreenShot:

[image]

this code (i check , images  are the same as the default except for colors.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
            android:drawable="@drawable/scrubber_track_red" />

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%"
                android:drawable="@drawable/scrubber_secondary_red" />
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%"
                android:drawable="@drawable/scrubber_primary_red" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and SeekBar

```
<SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekTrack"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/scrubber_progress_red"
                android:thumb="@drawable/scrubber_control_red"
                android:indeterminate="false"
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>
```

Images i got from aforementioned service (android holo colors)

Comment: Post some code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your drawables, there's probably a gradient in there somewhere as opposed to a solid color. I'd guess that the problem is in `@drawable/scrubber_progress_red`. Replace it temporarily with something like `@android:color/holo_green_light`. If the gradient goes away, we'll know that the `scrubber_progress_red` drawable is the problem.

Also, what is the name of the file that the layer-list is in?

Comment: Name of file is scrubber_progress_red.xml ,  and this http://img.by/i/OrtSK.png is @drawable/scrubber_primary_red (without gradient)

Comment: Could you also upload `scrubber_secondary_red` and `scrubber_track_red`?

Comment: Thans for the help , I already solve my problem , The couse of trouble is names of images doesn't consist .9 at the end , withou .9 image can't screth.